# How to make the class as an IEnumerable in C#?

Tags: c#, class, ienumerable

So I've got a class and a generic List inside of it, but it is private.

```
class Contacts
{
    List<Contact> contacts;
    ...
}
```

I want to make the class work as this would do:

```
foreach(Contact in contacts) .... ;
```

like this (not working):

```
Contacts c;
foreach(Contact in c) .... ;
```

In the example above the Contact class instance c has to yield return every item from contacts(private member of c)

How do I do it? I know it has to be IEnumerable with yield return, but where to declare that?

Answer (score 41):

Implement the interface IEnumerable:

```
class Contacts : IEnumerable<Contact>
{
    List<Contact> contacts;

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable
    public IEnumerator<Contact> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return contacts.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between them?

Comment: @John: Between the two method? One is the implementation of IEnumerable and one is IEnumarable<>. When you implement IEnumarable<>, you must also implement IEnumarable.

Comment: But I get this error on second method 'Contacts.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()': containing type does not implement interface 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: @John: At compile? I copy pasted that directly in a solution and it compiles and works fine.

Comment: ow, it inherits IENumerable... sorry

Comment: Doesn't compile indeed.

Answer (score 16):

Or return an `IEnumerator<Contact>` by providing a `GetEnumerator` method:

```
class Contacts
{
    List<Contact> contacts;

    public IEnumerator<Contact> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var contact in contacts)
            yield return contact;
    }
}
```

The `foreach` looks for `GetEnumerator`. Have a look here for the language specification details regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679993/284240

[How to make a Visual C# class usable in a foreach statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022/en-us)

Comment: @TimeSchmelter: And how is the foreach going to know that this class implement a GetEnumerator method if it has no interface to declare the implementation contract?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras: The `foreach` looks for `GetEnumerator`. Have a look here for the language specification details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3679993/284240

Comment: Interresting. Always been under the impression that the interface was mandatory. Good to know. "The disadvantage of omitting IEnumerable and IEnumerator is that the collection class is no longer interoperable with the foreach statements, or equivalents, of other common language runtime-compatible languages."... Oww... That's a killer.

Comment: This answer is enough if we are using List.

Comment: Couldn't you just directly access the `List<Contacts>`? i. e. `foreach (var contact in contacts.contacts)`

Comment: @luke: Yes, if it's public, but that was not the question here. OP wanted to know how to make a class behave like an enumerable, so as if the class `Contacts` would be a collection itself. So `foreach(Contact contact in c) .... ` if `c` is an instance of `Contacts`.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Contacts: IEnumerable
{
     ...... 
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return contacts.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Should do a trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new Contacts();
        var a = new Contact() { Name = "a" };
        var b = new Contact() { Name = "b" };
        var c = new Contact() { Name = "c" };
        var d = new Contact() { Name = "d" };
        list.ContactList = new List<Contact>();
        list.ContactList.Add(a);
        list.ContactList.Add(b);
        list.ContactList.Add(c);
        list.ContactList.Add(d);

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        }
    }
}

class Contacts : IEnumerable<Contact>
{
    public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Contact> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ContactList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ContactList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about just extending `List<Contact>`

If you don't want to extend any other class its a very simple, fast option:

```
class Contacts :List<Contact>
{   
}
```

Comment: It might not be an answer to the question, as posed, but I believe this answer is seriously underestimated. Extending `List<Contact>` might very well be the best solution in some cases! :-)

Comment: This is a good approach. Tim's answer may be preferable in cases where one seeks to prevent free modification of the list by forcing the caller to interact with exposed methods only.