# C# Data Annotations - Set properties Model with Display name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have a list with Strings of Display names of Model:

```
public class TVSystemViewData : BaseViewData
    {
        [Display(Name = "AccountId", Description = "")]
        public String AccountId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AllocatedManagedMemory", Description = "")]
        public String AllocatedManagedMemory { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AllocatedPhysicalMemory", Description = "")]
        public String AllocatedPhysicalMemory { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AudioMute", Description = "")]
        public String AudioMute { get; set; }
}
```

I need to set the properties with a foreach loop to add the values to my Model:

This is how get values from POST the application

```
var model.AccountId = shell.getParameter("AccountId")
var model.AllocatedManagedMemory = shell.getParameter("AllocatedManagedMemory");
```

The shell.GetParameter get the value from a POST.

this is how i want:
I have a a Method to get all Display attr

```
public List<String> GetTVSystemProperties()
{
    return typeof(TVSystemViewData)
        .GetProperties()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true) //select many because can have multiple attributes
            .Select(e => ((DisplayAttribute)e))) //change type from generic attribute to DisplayAttribute
        .Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Name) //select not null and take only name
        .ToList();
}
```

My collection is a list of Strings
ex: collection {"AccountId","AllocatedManagedMemory"...}

My model is TVSystemViewData

```
foreach (item in collection)
{
    if(item == modelProperty name){
         // i don know how
         model.property = shell.getParameter(item)
    }
}
```

[UPDATED]
I am using this:

```
        foreach (var property in UtilsHandler.getConfigAsList("sysDataSource"))
        {
            //Set Values to Model
            try
            {
                model.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(model, shell.getParameter(property), null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
Have issue with data types 
            }
        }
```

I have issues with data types.
But i use one foreach loop.
Still looking for a best method

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Are you writing a custom model binder?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the class inherit from IEnumerator, or add a GetEnumerator method yourself.

```
var model = new TVSystemViewData();

foreach(var item in model)
{
  item.AccountId = shell.getParameter("AccountId");
  //item.AllocatedManagedMemory ...
}
```

Please refer to this post for more information : [How to make the class as an IEnumerable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135443/how-to-make-the-class-as-an-ienumerable-in-c)

Check this article out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322022/how-to-make-a-visual-c-class-usable-in-a-foreach-statement

//EDIT. Forgot this part :

```
    List<TVSystemViewData> model;

    [Display(Name = "AccountId", Description = "")]
    public String AccountId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AllocatedManagedMemory", Description = "")]
    public String AllocatedManagedMemory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AllocatedPhysicalMemory", Description = "")]
    public String AllocatedPhysicalMemory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AudioMute", Description = "")]
    public String AudioMute { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<TVSystemViewData> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

EDIT According to your update question: I don't know if this is the way to go but it should work.

```
var model = new TVSystemViewData();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TVSystemViewData).GetProperties();
        List<string> items = new List<string> { "AccountId", "AllocatedManagedMemory" }; //your collection of strings


        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (item == property.Name)
                {
                    property.SetValue(model, shell.getParameter(item));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I Update the question with more detail. In your Answer i have to do always model.AccountId = some; model.AudioMute=some; I have 68 properties to model

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it helps. At least maybe point you in the right direction, also a similar topic, check it out if this doesn't help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151888/c-sharp-iterate-through-class-properties

Comment: I update with the code i use.
remove one of your foreach.

Comment: You should add the error that you are getitng. I tried your updated thing and works fine. Does shell.gerParameter(item) return you a string? I suppose, but does the "UtilsHandler.getConfigAsList("sysDataSource")" give you the correct  data type string?  Why do you iterate that instead of your list of strings you mentioned?

Comment: the shell return always a string. you can surround with try catch. Or you can make a switch with datatypes and do a tryparse... this is just a ideia