# When does foreach resolve the container?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

```
foreach(Value v in myDictionary[key])
```

In this scenario, is the compiler able to determine that myDictionary[key] will always be the same and not hash the [key] every iteration of foreach?

```
foreach(Value v in myEnumerable.Where(s => s.IsTrue))
```

I know enumerables are lazy, I suspect that in this case, the .Where only resolves once and returns a full collection for the foreach but that is only a hunch.

Judging by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679805/how-does-foreach-call-getenumerator-via-ienumerable-reference-or-via) question, the foreach is doing a .GetEnumerable even in scenario 1, so its the return of that which is used so therefore it only resolves once and not on every iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`foreach` in C# is just a syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816794/1163867).

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

gets expanded into

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

As you can see, `x` is only used once, to get the enumerator by calling `GetEnumerator` on it. So your dictionary lookup will only be executed once. Later on it does only care about that enumerator, not where it came from.