# Why is Dictionary transformed into a KeyValuePair here?

Tags: c#

I'm just messing around with some data types of C# in order to understand them.
I've been trying for a while to understand why this dictionary is turned into a KeyValuePair.
Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> operatii(int a, int b)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> calculare = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        calculare.Add("suma", a + b);
        calculare.Add("produs", a * b);
        return calculare;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(Dictionary<string, int> dict in operatii(5, 6))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>'

Now as I'm writing this I've understood that my logic was flawed, and the first parameter of the foreach cannot be a Dictionary.

But how does C# know that this should've been a KeyValuePair? Maybe I really meant to write Dictionary in there, and make the foreach run only once (because I only have one Dictionary).

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach(Dictionary<string, int> dict in operatii(5, 6))` When you loop through a `List<int>` - every entry in it isn't a `List<int>`. It is an `int`. The exact same principle applies to `Dictionary`. The entries aren't dictionaries. They are keyvaluepairs.

Comment: `Maybe I really meant to write Dictionary in there, and make the foreach run only once (because I only have one Dictionary).` Maybe that is your _intent_ but it won't work. Looping doesn't work like that. If I loop through a box of apples, I am looping through the apples one by one. I can't decide to get a box (rather than an individual apple) instead. That doesn't make sense, loop-wise.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the enumerator of the `Dictionary` by calling `foreach` - and the `foreach` will give you access to the elements.

This is by design; see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

```
foreach (var element in enumerable)
```

The compiler is trying to tell you that you're trying to squeeze the whole dictionary in a single element: the Key ValuePair. (note; this is an analogy: the actual reason is about type mismatch, not about size. C# is type safe which means you can only assign something to a type which has the same - possibly through inheritance - type)

Similar as if you `foreach` over an `int[]` array, the element in the loop will be an `int`, and not the array itself, `int[]`.

So, for your code:

Your method is of type Dictionary<>:

```
//the Dictionary is enumerable 
//an element is the KeyValuePair
Dictionary<string, int> operatii(int a, int b)
```

So, in the loop:

```
//  this should be an element    in    the enumeratable
foreach(Dictionary<string, int> dict in operatii(5, 6))
```

Or its equivalent:

```
var array = new int[] {1,2,3};

// element is of type ìnt`
foreach(int element in array)
```

To fix it:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> dict in operatii(5, 6))
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your time. So each data type has a GetEnumerator method, which will tell the compiler what each element of the loop will be? For example, for a Tuple<int, int>, how will the compiler know which data type to use?

Comment: Hi, not all data types have it - its about having the IEnumerable interface implemented. Most lists, collections and array have it. The Tuple doesn't I believe. Here is a list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

> But how does C# know that this should've been a KeyValuePair?

Because `Dictionary` has a [`GetEnumerator` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_GetEnumerator), and the `foreach` loop [knows to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679805/11683) this method. The method represents a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, hence the compiler can generate the message.

> Maybe I really meant to write Dictionary in there, and make the foreach run only once (because I only have one Dictionary).

Then you should have your method return a collection of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. Such as e.g. `static List<Dictionary<string, int>> operatii(int a, int b)`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` lets you execute code *for each* separate element in the list. So it unpacks the dictionary into a sequence of key-value pairs.

See the other answers for more details